# No Pie Chart Data available

Tags: android, kotlin, pie-chart

I'm developing an android application and in this app, I'm trying to display a pie chart in one of fragments. But it shows "No chart data available". When I try to do the same in an activity, it shows perfectly. I'm using the "MPAndroidChart" as a reference.I have even checked it on Stack Overflow but It does not give any useful conclusions Hence I have to ask this question again. Please Help I am New to Kotlin
Following is the code of my Fragment Activity :

```
    val pieChart : PieChart = view.findViewById(R.id.pieChart)
    val dataEntries = arrayListOf<PieEntry>()
    dataEntries.add(PieEntry(30.0f))
    dataEntries.add(PieEntry(40.0f))
    dataEntries.add(PieEntry(30.0f))
    pieChart.animateXY(1000,1000)

    val colors: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#4DD0E1"))
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#FFF176"))
    colors.add(Color.parseColor("#FF8A65"))


    val pieDataSet = PieDataSet(dataEntries, "This is Pie Chart label")
    val pieData = PieData(pieDataSet)
    pieData.setDrawValues(true)
    pieData.notifyDataChanged()
    pieChart.invalidate()
```

Below is my Xml File, It was some more code like Spinner and Frame layout but the pie Chart part is below inside the Child Linear Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".fragments.SettingsFragment">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:background="@drawable/activity_drawable">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/option1"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/option2"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        />

</FrameLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/pieChart"
            android:layout_width="348dp"
            android:layout_height="306dp"
            android:layout_margin="35dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"

            />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I see you never Set `pieData` to `pieChart` . you need set it to `pieChart` . Calling `notifyDataChanged()` or `invalidate()` will not have any effect because you never set the data set .

Comment: you need to set it like `pieChart.setData(pieData);` . It should work then

Answer (score 0):

You never set `PieData` to `PieChart` so Calling `notifyDataChanged()` or `invalidate()` will not have any effect. Set the data as below .

```
pieChart.setData(pieData)
```